# VBA Macro Works on sheet 1 but not on Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone tell me how to avoid running out of memory? I have 2 worksheets that i used the following code to change the hyperlink location from 26->95. it worked on sheet 2 but on sheet 1 it keeps on saying out of memory, whilst on sheet 2 there's no problem n my hyperlinks location successfully changed. any idea? thank u. much appreciated

```
 Sub HyperLinkChange()
   Dim oldtext As String
   Dim newtext As String
   Dim h As Hyperlink

   oldtext = "My002vs0026"
   newtext = "my002vs0095"


   For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
   x = InStr(1, h.Address, oldtext)
   If x > 0 Then
       If h.TextToDisplay = h.Address Then
            h.TextToDisplay = newtext
       End If
       h.Address = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
       Substitute(h.Address, oldtext, newtext)
   End If
   Next
End Sub
```

current hyperlinks loc are file:///\My002vs0026\dept$\filename
new hyperlinks loc are file:///\my002vs0095\dept$\filename

and when i used the following codes, only partial of the sheet 1 hyperlinks changed while some remains same:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeHyperlinks()
    Dim h As Long
    Dim oldDr As String, newDr As String
    oldDr = "\My002vs0026\"
    newDr = "\my002vs0095\"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            For h = 1 To .Hyperlinks.Count
            With .Hyperlinks(h)
                'Debug.Print .Address
                .Address = Replace(.Address, oldDr, newDr, 1, -1,     vbTextCompare)
                'Debug.Print .Address
            End With
        Next h
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would change the line: `h.Address = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
       Substitute(h.Address, oldtext, newtext)` to: `h.Address = Replace(h.Address, oldtext, newtext)`

Comment: Your code works in my case, so a change isn't that neccessary for it. Maybe it's just the amount of replacing everything, so the data in your sheet. You should upload a screenshot of your data and not the shown text but the hyperlink-URL.

Comment: Try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the beginning, right after your declarations. At the end of your code, set both to true again.

Comment: hi @DawidSATokyo, i tried changing it but it still says out of memory :(

Comment: hello @Irithyll, ya i was thinking too, bcuz the sheet 2 works fine with the codes as it is rather like 40% lesser in numbers of hyperlinks compared to in sheet 1. im not sure whether this is the factor as im actually still new and was assigned this task :(

Comment: hi @Sun, it didnt work. any idea? :(

Comment: I found this link, where some specific links seemed to cause the error. Try and give this a read: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/803281-run-time-error7-out-memory-error.html

Comment: @Sun, hello. thank you. I have actually solved it by running it on notepad instead of macro and it was done easily. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by using notepad:

1)  Save the Excel spreadsheet, as a Single Web Page.
2)  Edit this page in (say) Notepad, by running the Find/Replace option.
3)  Save this Notepad file, as an Excel File - Job done.

*steps was found on the net